# Cakephp can't update data in shell file

Tags: php, shell, cakephp

The below shell script is supposed to update the Notification.emailed database cell once an email notification has been sent but it is not working. I have tried the save method and the saveField method but they are not working. I called the shell from the console and there are no errors and $id and $email display on screen as per the last 2 lines of the script. I am unable to debug as there is no error. Please help.

Here is the part of my shell script:

```
<?php
App::uses('CakeEmail', 'Network/Email');

class EmailnotificationShell extends AppShell {

public $uses = array('User', 'Notification');

public function fsnotify() {

    $notifications = $this->Notification->find('all', array(
    'recursive' => 1,
    'conditions' => array('Notification.viewed' => '0', 'Notification.emailed' => '0', 'User.emailauth' => '1'),
    'group' => array('Notification.user_id')
    ));

    foreach ($notifications as $notification){

    $email = $notification['User']['email'];
    $id = $notification['Notification']['id'];

      $this->Notification->id = $id;
      // $this->Notification->saveField('emailed', 1, array('validate' => false, 'callbacks' => false));

      $data = array('Notification.emailed' => 1);
      $this->Notification->save($data);
      $this->Notification->clear();
     // below lines for testing in console
      $this->out($id);
      $this->out($email);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't prefix the column name with the alias in the save data array. So the following:-

```
$data = array('Notification.emailed' => 1);
$this->Notification->save($data);
```

Should be:-

```
$data = array('emailed' => 1);
$this->Notification->save($data);
```

If it's still not saving then try checking for any validation errors:-

```
debug($this->Notification->invalidFields());
```

Just because there's no obvious error doesn't mean there's no way to debug your code! :-)

Comment: Thank you @drmonkeyninja for your help. You fixed my problem and it works now! I thought I had already tried that earlier but turns out I hadn't.